# Show updated rows when data is refreshed in an excel spreadsheet

Tags: sql, excel, pivot-table

I have an excel spreadsheet that is created using a SQL query and connected to a database. Periodically data will be updated in the SQL table and therefore when i refresh the data in the spreadsheet it will change.

Is there a way to display the changed rows and show what the changes were?

Answer (score 0):

One way I can think off involves using VBA. You can use `Worksheet_SelectionChange` function, then use `Target.Address` to change the back colour of each cell who's value has changed. For obvious reasons you will have to reset the back colour of all cells in your worksheet when the workbook opens (again achievable with VBA)